# PHP delete button on HTML table

Tags: php, html, delete-row

I have outputted the results from a MySQL table to an HTML table. In the last column, I want a delete function to work for the specific row but my code doesn't seem to work.

I have now adjusted my code due to the comments you kind people have left me and it is now recognizing the row it needs to delete but will not delete it? I am properly stumped with this one!

Again if anybody can explain this to me and provide code examples to correct this then thank you.

This is my code for the page:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

<tr>
    <th>AdoptionID</th>
    <th>UserID</th>
    <th>AnimalID</th>
    <th>Cancel</th>
<tr>

<?php
include("PHP/Connection.php");

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adoptionrequest` WHERE `userID` = '1' AND `approved` = 'Awaiting Approval' ");

while($requests=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    echo"<tr>";

    echo "<td>".$requests['adoptionID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$requests['userID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$requests['animalID']."</td>";
    ?>
    <td>
        <form action='PHP/Delete.php?id=<?php echo $requests['adoptionID'];?>' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="adoptionID" value="<?php echo $requests['adoptionID']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="submit"></form>
    </td>

    <?php
    echo"<tr>";
}

?>

</table>
```

and for the Delete.php:

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE adoptionID=$id LIMIT 1";
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE adoptionID={$_POST['adoptionID']}` that should be a GET while using `isset()`. Plus, SQL injection is imminent.

Comment: Or use `$_POST['name']`... And you should probably add `include("PHP/Connection.php");` to the top of your delete script.

Answer (score 0):

Change the field name in the HTML form

```
<form action='PHP/delete.php' method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="adoptionID" value="<?php echo $requests['adoptionID']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="submit">
</form>
```

Modfity delete.php

```
<?php
// Casting it to an int protects against SQL injection
$adoptionID = (int)$_POST['adoptionID'];

//Define the query
$query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE adoptionID={$adoptionID} LIMIT 1";

//sends the query to delete the entry
mysql_query($query); // <- You should be using mysqli_query
```

Comment: in the delete.php im getting the error "Unidentified index adoptionID" why is this?

Comment: There is no POST variable `adoptionID`. It means you haven't modified the HTML. The hidden should have the attribute `name="adoptionID"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE adoptionID={$_POST['adoptionID']} LIMIT 1";
```

has invalid post data. try

```
  $x = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['adoptionID']);
  $query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE adoptionID=$x LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with single quotes in `{$_POST['adoptionID']}`. Look at the comments above. Issue is either `$_GET` as `adoptionID` is in the form action url, or use `$_POST` with `name` as that is the input with the `adoptionID`.

Comment: @Sean I was missing that.

Comment: still open to SQL injection, *say bye-bye database*. `;Drop table xxx;--`

Comment: @Fred-ii- laughing to people is not a good option. instead, help them by letting them to fix their mistake.

Comment: @ctwheels well, not really. Lordie, I wouldn't want mine to be dropped. However, I run a regular backup, so I'm good. Never let one's guard down ;-)

Comment: @AliTorabi who said I was laughing? people shouldn't put words in my mouth, but a nice croissant would be nice.

Comment: @AliTorabi Please note that the combination of `mysql_real_escape_string()` and an **un-quoted** value in the sql statement still leaves you wide open to sql injection. Cast to `int` or if you want to treat is as a string, quote it in the query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- technically `;Drop table xxx;--` won't work in this exact situation since `mysql_query()` will not execute 2 queries, but `1 OR 1=1` certainly would.

Comment: @Sean a mere example. but I'll stand corrected on the `1 OR 1=1` ;-) `WHERE col = 'xxx');Drop table xxxxx;--`

Comment: basically, the question wasn't about the security issue, however a good idea!

Comment: try putting `$_POST['adoptionID']` into a variable

Comment: @AliTorabi The question is not about security, but if you post an answer on SO that contains an obvious sql injection hole, it will probably get downvoted :-)